# Rendering Problems after add image in Android Studio

Tags: image, user-interface, android-studio

Only what I want is add image to my app. Everytime i get this error:

> Rendering Problems:
>
> The following classes could not be found:
>   android.support.v7.widget.AppCompactImageView(open class, show
>   Exception.......

I tried two things to solve this error:
   1. Change API 
   2. add Basic. to Styles

Nothing working... Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and I fixed it by changing the name of the image I was trying to add. The problem was that the image's name started with a number so try to edit the name and see if it helps.